# Are you allowed to post incomplete programs that you still want reviewed?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Are you allowed to post incomplete programs that you still want reviewed? I made the start of a battleship game, but I want people's opinion before I finish it.

Comment: as long as the code demonstrably works as intended ...

Comment: Did you read our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) helps out:

> I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?
>
> Simply ask yourself the following questions. To be on-topic the answer must be "yes" to all questions:
>
> - Is code included directly in my question? (See Make sure you include your code in your question below.)
> - Am I an owner or maintainer of the code?
> - Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> - Do I want the code to be good code? (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> - To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?
> - Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?
>
> If you answered "yes" to all the above questions, your question is on-topic for Code Review.

Your Battleship game doesn't have to be finished to be reviewable. But the parts that have been implemented should work as intended. So we don't review general application lay-outs if the components of it haven't been implemented.

It's perfectly allowed to post something that only does the bare minimum while the end product you want to build contains much, much more.

For example, I once [wrote an elevator management system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105843/messed-up-elevator-management-system) which didn't support opening the elevator doors and the speed of the elevators was next to infinite. There was a small disclaimer:

> This project is not finished. However, I think the current state is perfectly reviewable since it's doing what it's supposed to do.

It was supposed to manage elevators. It managed elevators. It wasn't code I'd ever want to show to a customer or a boss, but it did something. It was reviewable.

If your Battleship game does the basic things while still missing a lot of other features, that's ok. For now, that's 'working as intended'.

Comment: That. Also worth noting, if your question reads like it's asking reviewers for help implementing the not-yet-written features, it's off-topic.